# nsdata writeToURL:atomically: returns true but my directory comes up null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, writetofile

I have been looking at this for hours and can't seem to figure out my problem. Here is my code

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
                    NSArray* urls = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];

                NSArray* directory = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:urls[0] includingPropertiesForKeys:@[@"NSCreatingDateKey"] options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles error:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@", directory);
                NSURL* pathURL = [[urls objectAtIndex:0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"stanfordpictures/"];
                if ([directory count] < 3) {
                    [fileManager createDirectoryAtURL:pathURL withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
                }
                NSString* pictureString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"picture%d.png", self.cacheCounter];
                NSURL* pictureURL = [pathURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:pictureString];
                NSURL* absolutePictureURL = [pictureURL absoluteURL];
                NSLog(@"%@", pictureURL);
               NSData *cacheImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
                if ([cacheImageData writeToURL:pictureURL atomically:YES])
                {
                    NSLog(@"It worked");
                    NSArray* cacheDirectory = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[pathURL absoluteString] error:nil];
                    NSLog(@"%@", cacheDirectory);
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"An error occurred");
                }
```

And here is my error log

```
2013-10-03 22:36:48.920 Assignment4[14754:c07] (
"file://localhost/Users/ddelnano/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/683F512B-7FFC-4C3E-9526-715B09AABD56/Library/Caches/com.DelNano.Dom.Assignment4/",
"file://localhost/Users/ddelnano/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/683F512B-7FFC-4C3E-9526-715B09AABD56/Library/Caches/Snapshots/",
"file://localhost/Users/ddelnano/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/683F512B-7FFC-4C3E-9526-715B09AABD56/Library/Caches/stanfordpictures/"
```

)

```
file://localhost/Users/ddelnano/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/683F512B-7FFC-4C3E-9526-715B09AABD56/Library/Caches/stanfordpictures/picture0.png
2013-10-03 22:36:49.031 Assignment4[14754:c07] It worked
2013-10-03 22:36:49.032 Assignment4[14754:c07] (null)
```

So basically my `NSData` `writeToFile:atomically:` is returning true but when I check the directory "stanfordphotos" the `NSFileManager` method returns a null array.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Avoid `-[NSURL absoluteString]` when passing arguments to NSFileManager, use -[\[NSURL path\]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/path) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above comment of CodaFi is great, Also the samething if you want to do you can do like this below. Though i have removed this line. if its required.                     `NSArray* cacheDirectory = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[pathURL absoluteString] error:nil];`So that you can directly fetch the name of file as a string inspite of an array, :-

```
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSArray* urls = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];

    NSArray* directory = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:urls[0] includingPropertiesForKeys:@[@"NSCreatingDateKey"] options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", directory);
    NSURL* pathURL = [[urls objectAtIndex:0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"stanfordpictures/"];
   if ([directory count] < 3) {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtURL:pathURL withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    }
    NSString* pictureString = @"hussain_2156.pptx";//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"picture%d.png", self.cacheCounter];
    NSURL* pictureURL = [pathURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:pictureString];
    NSLog(@"%@", pictureURL);
    NSData *cacheImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/hussain/Desktop/hussain_2156.pptx"];
    if ([cacheImageData writeToURL:pictureURL atomically:YES])
    {
        NSLog(@"It worked");
        NSString *file=nil;
        NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:[pathURL path]];
        while(file =[dirEnum nextObject])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",file);
        }
    }
    else
    {

        NSLog(@"An error occurred");
    }
```

Comment: Wow I knew it had to be something simple.